# How to publish oracle APEX application URL

Tags: oracle-apex

After I installed oracle APEX and built my application, How can I share/publish 
application URL to Other Computer connected via the same router ?..

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from your other computer accessing the same network, launch a browser, then type the address to your Apex application, which usually follows the format:

> http:// [your-IP-Address]:[assigned-port]/apex/f?p=[Application-Number]:[Page-number]

So you need the following information:

1. **IP Address** - actually, the IPv4 address of the computer that has your Oracle Apex installation. Depending on your system,you can get this in a variety of ways (in windows for
   example, go to the command prompt of said computer then type: ipconfig)
2. **Assigned port number** - this is usually 8080, but you may have customized
   this during installation.
3. **Application number** - this refers to the number assigned by Apex to
   your App
4. **Page number** - this is the page of your app that you designate to be
   the landing page-- usually the login page.

As an example, it may look like:

```
http://192.168.8.115:8080/apex/f?p=100:1
```

So in the above case, my app number is 100 (go to your application list to see this number), and my landing page is page 1, which is the designated login page inside my app #100.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much,, and as addition: 
I had to allow the port number through windows fire-well or turn fire-well off.

Comment: can we deploy apex web app as public website? hosting etc ... ?

Answer (score 0):

By default your HTTP port is disabled, first you have to make it enabled.

To do it, this command needs to be executed:

```
(execute dbms_xdb.setListenerLocalAccess(l_access => FALSE);)
```